# p:commandButton in p:dialog not working

Tags: jquery, jsf-2, primefaces, dialog, java-ee-6

I would like to use a p:dialog which contains some commandButtons, but I can not call my bean from the command button and don't know why.

On the xhtml page there aere two forms, the first form contains some stuff, like panels, panelgrids, buttons, etc.
The second form contains only my dialog.

My beanHandler (beanHandler) is ViewAccessScoped.
Everything on this xhtml page is working only my p:panel is not working

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:m="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components/mmnet">

 <h:form id="activityForm"> 
    <p:panel >

...
...

   <f:facet name="footer">

...

   <p:commandButton id="readyButton"
                                action="#{beanHandler.toggleStatus()}"
                                rendered="#{beanHandler.ready}"
                                value="#{labels.erledigt}"
                                icon="ui-icon-check"
                                update="@form :dialogForm"
                                onclick="dlg.show()">
               <p:tooltip for="readyButton" style="width:300px;">
                            <h:outputText value="#{messages.adviceWfEventActivityFinish}" />
              </p:tooltip>
   </p:commandButton>
          </f:facet>     

  </p:panel>

</h:form>

<h:form id="dialogForm">
    <p:outputPanel id="justAPanel">

        <p:dialog header="Ticket schließen?" widgetVar="dlg" resizable="false" appendToBody="true" rendered="#{beanHandler.lastActivity}" id="dlg"> 

            <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-bottom:10px"> 
                <h:outputLabel value="Soll das Ticket geschlossen werden?" />
                <p:spacer />

                <p:commandButton id="yesButton"
                                               value="#{labels.ja}" update=":workflowContentPanel"
                                               onclick="dlg.hide()"
                                              action="#{beanHandler.closeTicket()}" process="@form"/> 

                <p:commandButton id="noButton" value="#{labels.nein}" update=":workflowContentPanel" onclick="dlg.hide()"/> 
            </h:panelGrid> 

        </p:dialog> 
        </p:outputPanel>
    </h:form>

</ui:composition>
```

If I use the page like shown above, the p:panel does not appear on buttonClick. If I change this part of the code

```
<p:dialog header="Ticket schließen?" widgetVar="dlg" resizable="false" appendToBody="true" rendered="#{beanHandler.lastActivity}" id="dlg">
```

to

```
<p:dialog header="Ticket schließen?" widgetVar="dlg" resizable="false" appendToBody="true" rendered="true" id="dlg">
```

(changed the attribute rendered to true) the dialog is shown, but my buttons are not working (calling the bean not possible).
If have no idea why this happens.

Anyone an idea?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the attribute `appendToBody` you append the actual dialog box direct to the `body`-element. Through that, it is not in the form anymore. Without a form around, there are no Bean calls possible. Possible solutions:

- put another `<h:form>` into the `p:dialog`
- change the `appendToBody` attribute accordingly, possibly set it `false` and move the `p:dialog` to another place (direct as a child of your already existing `<h:form>`)

Hope it helps...

Comment: I should use nested forms?

Comment: Of course not! Or well, kind of: Primefaces appends your dialog to the body of the page (check the generated HTML via e.g. Firebug). So it's outside the form-tag. Best solution is to skip the `appendToBody` attribute and manually set the `p:dialog` as a direct child of the form-tag. Another solution is to, yes, add another `<h:form` into the dialog itself (ontested).

Comment: @LStrike any success?

Comment: No success at the moment. I moved this topic for my self and try to solve it later, not the time at the momemt. I will come back and tell if there is something new. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: I have made up a solution. I moved the dialog to another page (starting page) and placed it outside my container where I do all teh other stuff. I wrapped it in an own form and everything is fine.